# Trying to get the fragment shader to output a list

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, realtime

I am trying to figure out a way to get the Fragment Shader to output a list of `gl_VertexID-s`.

I want to use the GPU to get a list of vertices in the viewing frustum.

Is there any way I can get a per fragment shader invocation variable or something else that is possible to use as a pointer to a texture? If it is not possible, is there a possibility to use a sparse texture to render to, using `gl_VertexID-s` as a pointer?.

I will be rendering about a million or two vertices at a time (using `GL_POINTS`), and the list should be tightly packed to be of use. Some work may be offloaded to the CPU, but this is part of a real-time render engine so the execution times need to be under 10ms.

I am using OpenGL 4.4.

Comment: What are you trying to do at a higher level? There is probably a better way than this particular... strangeness.

Comment: I am trying to render a large amount of point cloud data stored in octrees and I would use this to traverse the octree. I know it's ambitious, but I didn't want to give up before asking around.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable, I'm just trying to avoid you asking about an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It helps to know the details of your ultimate goal, because there may be a better way to do this than trying to "output a list" with the fragment shader.

Comment: The rendering part is actually working, but I need this for optimization. I am currently using a 1D texture and gl_VertexID-s and tightly packing the list on the CPU, but this eats away all the bandwidth of the PCIe 3.0 and is creating a huge bottleneck.

Comment: While it is possible to do what you want using atomics and shader storage buffers, it would be absurdly slow. Why don't you just let the GPU handle culling in the normal pipeline? 1-2 million is reasonable to throw whole at modern chips.

Comment: I use this method for multiple passes. While the number of vertices I throw a the GPU actually sums up at about 16 million per frame, the number of points that get culled is many orders of magnitude greater. On every pass the GPU processes about a million vertices, each of which have 8 child nodes of which 4 on average are empty. Of those 4 on an average of 3 get culled because of distance from camera. For around 16 passes it means I only have to pass a quarter of a billionth (0.25^16) of the vertices to the GPU. The geometry data itself is massievly instanced (think of blades of grass).